# ArcGIS Server Manager - access problem

Tags: arcgis-server

I setup ArcServer 10 with postinstall and restart and I am getting the following error when I try accessing ArcServer Manager through URL:

> ```
> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /arcgismanager on this server.
> ```

I can admire that i am a member of agsadmin group.

[image]

Comment: Which Operating System? Windows 2003/8 Server?

Comment: Would the assumption that you are running under linux/Java using apache be correct? Please provide as much detail as possible when you ask your question. Throw us a bone. It makes it close to impossible to help without DETAILS.

Comment: I am running under windows xp (SP3)/Java, apache. Sorry for my incompetence, but i am not sure what kind of information should i provide. I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default URL for ArcGIS Server Manager is:

http://hostname/arcgis/manager/

If you've set an instance name, then the URL for the Manager would be:

http://hostname/instance/manager

Are you launching the Manager from a link, or by typing in its address?  Are you missing the slash between `arcgis` and `manager` ?

Did you specify an instance name when you ran the "Web Applications Post Install"?

You might have to run it again to reset the web applications (Manager is one of them)

Comment: I am lunching from a link as welll as by typing address. I tried with and without slash. Yes, i specify an instance name with post installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem but in the ArcGIS Server Manager you have to enter your domain/servername in front of your username like this:

User name: DOMAIN\user

Comment: true, but the point is that i can't have this log screen. Just after i open ArcGis manager i get this message...

Comment: Are you trying to access it from the server itself? or from outside? This sounds more like a webserver security issue. What webserver are you using?

Comment: i am trying to run it on localhost

Comment: did you install ArcGIS Server as an administrator or your own username?

Comment: I install as my own username- this might cause a problem. i will try to reinstall it. by now thanks a lot

Comment: I reinstall ArcGis Server 10 (now with administrator rights) and it did not help. I am confused because i am doing everything like i do with installation of ArcGis Server 9.3. Anyway i still get the same messeage (403 Forbidden). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something to do involving your firewall and/or intranet and/or your IIS setup. We need more information on your configuration of the machine the Server has been installed on to help further.